# Get some set of array based on condition from two arrays of array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I have two arrays of array in Javascript like

```
var array1 = [[10, 2], [11, 4], [12, 30], [13, 17], [14, 28]];
var array2 = [[8, 13], [9, 19], [10, 6], [11, 7], [12, 1]];
```

I want to get the set of arrays from `array1` which match the first element of each array of the `array2`

in my example case both `array1` and `array2` have array with first element as `10` `11` and `12`, so it should return

```
[[10, 2], [11, 4], [12, 30]];
```

is there any easy and efficient way using pure javscript or lodash, underscor framework or something like that. Without iterate over and match one by one of this two array ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ES6, you could use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
var array1 = [[10, 2], [11, 4], [12, 30], [13, 17], [14, 28]],
    array2 = [[8, 13], [9, 19], [10, 6], [11, 7], [12, 1]],
    set = new Set(array2.map(a => a[0])),
    result = array1.filter(a => set.has(a[0]));

console.log(result);
```

Version with an object as hash table

```js
var array1 = [[10, 2], [11, 4], [12, 30], [13, 17], [14, 28]],
    array2 = [[8, 13], [9, 19], [10, 6], [11, 7], [12, 1]],
    result = array1.filter(function (a) {
        return this[a[0]];
    }, array2.reduce(function (r, a) { 
        r[a[0]] = true;
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: this works too, upvoted but I actually do not want to bound in ES6, it should work every version

Comment: @Mostafiz, please have a look to version 2.

Answer (score 3):

You can use lodash [_.intersectWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.3#intersectionWith) function in order to solve this problem in an inline.

```
_.intersectionWith(array1, array2, function(a, b) {
    return a[0] === b[0];
});
```

I don't know about performance cos I haven't had the chance to have a look at the source code of this function. Anyway, I like it for its simplicity. Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwbm3xtg/1/) in case you want to check it out.

Answer (score 2):

If you can make use of [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), then you can compute the a set of numbers to look for first and use `.filter` to only get the arrays whose first element is in that set:

```
var haystack = new Set(array2.map(x => x[0]));
var newArray = array1.filter(x => haystack.has(x[0]));
```

Of course you can also use the lodash or underscore versions of `.map` and `.filter`.

---

Alternatives to using `Set` would be:

- Create an array of numbers instead and use `indexOf` to test existence. That will scale linearly with the number of elements:

  ```
  var haystack = array2.map(x => x[0]);
  var newArray = array1.filter(x => haystack.indexOf(x[0]) > -1);
  ```
- Create an object with `number -> true` entries to test existence with `in`, `hasOwnProperty` or just object access:

  ```
  var haystack = array2.reduce((obj, x) => (obj[x[0]] = true, obj), {});
  var newArray = array1.filter(x => haystack[x[0]]);
  ```

Which one performs better depends on the number of elements you have and the environment the code is running in.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `filter()` and `find()`

```js
var array1 = [
  [10, 2],
  [11, 4],
  [12, 30],
  [13, 17],
  [14, 28]
];
var array2 = [
  [8, 13],
  [9, 19],
  [10, 6],
  [11, 7],
  [12, 1]
];

var result = array1.filter(function(ar) {
  return array2.find(function(e) {
    return e[0] == ar[0]
  })
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) anf [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) combo in ES6 as follows;

```js
var array1 = [[10, 2], [11, 4], [12, 30], [13, 17], [14, 28]],
    array2 = [[8, 13], [9, 19], [10, 6], [11, 7], [12, 1]],
         m = new Map(array2),
    array3 = array1.filter(a => m.has(a[0]));
console.log(array3);
```

If you need backwards compatibility other answers are pretty good.